# What grass types will survive in areas of standing water that last for up to a week?

Tags: plant-recommendations, grass

I own a mobile home in a very nice development. My yard is sinking and over the past 3 years the grass has died in that area.  The development owners say it's my responsibility to add topsoil to the low areas.  I can't afford to do that at this time.  Is there any grass that I can grow in areas that have standing water for up to a week at times? I appreciate any tips or suggestions anyone can offer.

Comment: This doesn't address your grass problem, but often on craigslist this time of year I see people getting rid of topsoil from their spring renovations. I've even seen multiple ads for free topsoil.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your profile says you're in the US, but that's a big place and different grasses grow in different regions. If you could share your [hardiness zone](http://planthardiness.ars.usda.gov/PHZMWeb/) with us, you'd likely get better suggestions for plants that are suitable for your climate. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't seed a good lawn in standing water, but when it is dry, [these lawn grasses](http://www.gardenguides.com/102724-grass-seeds-shady-wet-areas.html) are likely your best choices. I used ryegrass and roughstalk bluegrass in similar areas with fair results. After the plants are established they will survive these conditions okay, but mowing and foot traffic will do a lot of damage. I am in a very low altitude valley and have lots of swampy areas. It would be best to level out the lawn with topsoil, and maybe add a drain system, although the latter is either time consuming or expensive. As you can see, my lawn is very wet also. It never dries out, so the ground is always wet. The grass grows well except in the areas where the mower blades actually cut below the water surface, and where the wheels push thm into the mud. [image]

Comment: Four inch drainpipe with sleeve is the gift that keeps on giving as far as drainage is concerned. Not that expensive either.

Comment: Very true. But there's the time.